# Django - Autocomplete Light in admin for join Model

Tags: django-admin, django-1.10, django-autocomplete-light

So I have a join model defined as follow:

```
class EventTrack(models.Model):
    dj = models.ForeignKey(DjProfile, blank=True)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.event, self.track)
```

Is there a way I can use [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst) with this model?
I know how to use it with inline models, but I don't get how to use it with standard field (in this case they are fk though).

At the moment I have the follow, which does not include the autocomplete functionality:

```
class EventTrackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['event', 'dj', 'track']
    list_display = ('event', 'dj', 'track')
    search_fields = ['event', 'dj', 'track']

admin.site.register(EventTrack, EventTrackAdmin)
```

### edit:

I defined a DjForm as follow:

```
class DjForm(ModelForm):
    dj = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=DjProfile.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='dj-autocomplete')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = DjProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class DjProfileAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return DjProfile.objects.none()

        qs = DjProfile.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

And routing:

```
from frontend.views import DjProfileAutocomplete

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^dj-autocomplete/$', DjProfileAutocomplete.as_view(create_field='name'), name='dj-autocomplete'),
]
```

Everything works fine, and if I browse the endpoint I get the json with Djs result. My only problem is to use this in the EventTrack Model, in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

sooo, actually it was easy:

forms.py

```
class EventTrackForm(ModelForm):
    dj = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=DjProfile.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='dj-autocomplete')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = EventTrack
        fields = '__all__'
```

admin.py

```
class EventTrackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EventTrackForm
    ...
```